# jQuery & AJAX to check if email exist in database on focusout doesn't work

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax

What I'm trying to do is simple; I just want to check if an email address is already in database when I focusout this input text. & so, get a success/error message.

But nothing appears, even when I'm trying to write an email address which is already in database

So I have this jQuery function:

```js
jQuery('#txt-mail-0').bind("focusout", function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("CheckEmailOfWorkflow")',
        data: { idWorkflow: clientInformation.idWorkflow, email: jQuery(this).val() },
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.result) {
                //ALREADY IN BASE = ERROR
                successGeneral.hide();
                successTxtEmail.hide();
                errorGeneral.show();
                errorTxtEmail.show();

                jQuery(this).removeClass("is - valid ");
                jQuery(this).removeClass("is - invalid ");

                jQuery("#btn-next-1").prop('disabled', true);
                jQuery(this).addClass("is - invalid ");
                jQuery(this).css("background", "#FAC8C8");
            }
            else {
                //NOT IN BASE = SUCCESS
                successGeneral.show();
                successTxtEmail.show();
                errorGeneral.hide();
                errorTxtEmail.hide();

                jQuery(this).removeClass("is - valid ");
                jQuery(this).removeClass("is - invalid ");

                jQuery("#btn-next-1").prop('disabled', false);
                jQuery(this).addClass("is - valid ");
                jQuery(this).css("background", "#E1E1E1");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Referring to this function in the Controller :

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckEmailOfWorkflow(int idWorkflow, string email)
{
    List < Staging > listeStaging = dataBase.getAllStagingByIdWorkflow(idWorkflow.ToString());
    foreach(Staging staging in listeStaging)
    {
        if (staging.Email == email) {
            return Json(true);
        }
    }
    return Json(false);
}
```

& finally, here's the DataAccess :

```cs
public List < Staging > getAllStagingByIdWorkflow(string idWorkflow)
{
    List < Staging > data = new List<Staging>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idWorkflow)) {
        try {
            data = _core.Fetch<Staging>(Sql.Builder.Where("ID_WORKFLOW=@0", idWorkflow));
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            return data;
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you done an debugging? Have you checked the browser's networking debug tab? The console tab? Have you set breakpoints in code to see if your methods are being hit? Have you added any `console.log`, etc. logging client-side? In short: what have you done to narrow this problem down?

Comment: Hi @John, Yes I've tried this :
jQuery('#text-mail-0').bind("focusout", function () { console.log("HELP"); });

& nothing appears in the console.

Comment: OK ...and? What are the results? Please give full details (in your question text) showing what diagnostics steps you have performed. Edit: I see you've edited it now. It seems like you don't have a text input with the id `text-mail-0`, or that the jquery is being executed before the DOM contains it.

Comment: Ok, it works.
I don't know why, but the problem was "if (data.result)" = KO, "if (data)" = OK